# How do I change my button's Text after it is pressed in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning as I go and am trying to create a simple app. I've run into this snag where I am setting up an event listener/callback method and want it to change the text of my button to something else.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    startButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    mainMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainMessage);
    InText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.InText);

    final Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);


    this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
    gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    startButton = setText("change my text");

                }



            }
    );
```

On the `startButton = setText("change my text");` line, I am getting the error:

> Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)'

Im still new to coding and understand most of the basics. In this same activity, I have gestures that can change the text of a textView to something else so I'm kinda stumped as to why this isn't working.

Comment: startButton.setText("change my text");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 startButton = setText("change my text");
```

to

```
 startButton.setText("change my text");
```